# I am using jqGrid and want to save column widths after they are resized

Tags: jqgrid, resize, save, width

I added the resizeStop event to my grid and it gets called, but I need to save the new column widths in the session and then use the new values to maintain the user preferences for column widths. Currently paging in the grid or reloading resets the column widths.

Here is what I have so far.

```
resizeStop: function(newwidth, index) {
            alert(index + " : " + newwidth);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it. I store all column widths in a HashMap in a bean I use to save session info. When the resizeStop event is fired I submit the new column size to a controller (I'm using Java and Spring) which updates the values in the HashMap.

Here are the code snippets:

```
resizeStop: function(newwidth, index) {
                var colModel = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
                $.post("/sessionState/columnWidth/update",
                    {
                        column: colModel[index].name,
                        width: newwidth
                    }
                )
            }
```

and in the colModel:

```
{name:'Title', index:'title', width: ${uiState.columnWidthMap["Title"]}, jsonmap: 'title', sorttype: "text"}
```